# DateFormatter for format 'Fri, 19 Jun 2015 20:05:23 GMT'

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to determine the DateFormatter dateFormat element for the following timestamp:

```
Fri, 19 Jun 2015 20:05:23 GMT
```

I have tried the following without success:

```
E', dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz
EE', dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz
EEE', dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz

E', dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zz
EE', dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zz
EEE', dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zz
```

Comment: what locale have you set.?

Comment: please check d answer, i have added and tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];

// "Fri, 19 Jun 2015 20:05:23 GMT"
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];
```

Comment: It was the timeZoneWithAbbreviation that was catching me out. Many thanks